# Found rows as per two columns together in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have some rows in my table like this**

```
Sno | sender | receiver
-----------------------
 1  |   A    |    B
 2  |   B    |    A
 3  |   A    |    B
 4  |   C    |    D
 5  |   D    |    C
 6  |   A    |    C
 7  |   C    |    D
 8  |   C    |    A
 9  |   A    |    C
```

What I am trying to do is that if sender and receiver found vice versa.

for e.g.

If I have **sender A** and **receiver B** in a row and in other row that sender A is **receiver A** and receiver B is **sender B**. This type of matching rows should be print(like my above table).
I tried a query like this :

```
select sender, receiver from table where (sender,receiver) = (receiver,sender)
```

but got nothing. What should be the **query to get same result as per above table**.

Comment: please post the expected output as well.

Comment: I don't believe that's valid SQL, unless MySQL provides syntactic sugar that I'm not aware of.  Let's hope you haven't named your table "table".

Comment: @vkp output will be like my table because i have some rows of this type of in my table

Answer (score 4):

If you want all rows where the pair appears in both directions:

```
select t.sender, t.receiver
from table t
where (t.sender, t.receiver) in (select t2.receiver, t2.sender from table t2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it's not giving expected data.

Comment: So, what's the expected data? (Edit the question.)

Comment: @Paramjeet . . . "If I have sender A and receiver B in a row and in other row that sender A is receiver A and receiver B is sender B.".  That is what the query in this answer does.  If you have another question, then ask it as another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Mistake at my side your query is working. Thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff For one thing I need your help. I just don't want the first row from matching data. For example, If sender A's and receiver B's vice versa data found in table. Result must not be included the first row and will return other matching rows. If you could please help me.

Comment: @Paramjeet . . . This answer answers *this* question.  If you have *another* question, ask it as *another* question, with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Exists`

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table1 b
               WHERE  a.sender = b.receiver
                      AND a.receiver = b.sender)
       AND NOT ( 'a' IN ( sender, receiver ) AND 'b' IN ( sender, receiver ) )
```

Your current query just compares with the same record instead of checking the existence in other records

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it's not giving expected data.

Comment: @Paramjeet - It is working as expected.. Check here http://rextester.com/ZYFAS40586

Comment: For one thing I need your help. I just don't want the first row from matching data. For example, If sender A's and receiver B's vice versa data found in table. Result must not be included the first row and will return other matching rows. If you could please help me.

Comment: thanks again but I was meant that for for matching rows. For example, from A and B record same type of three rows found like A and B, B and A, A and B so i don't want the first one other two must print.

Comment: @Paramjeet - Ask a new question that involves more changes

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5c70b/3

```
create table t(
    Sno int,
    sender char(10),
    receiver char(10)
);


Insert Into t (Sno, sender, receiver)
Values
 (1,'A','B'),
 (2,'B','A'),
 (3,'A','B'),
 (4,'C','D'),
 (5,'D','C'),
 (6,'A','C'),
 (7,'C','D'),
 (8,'C','A'),
 (9,'A','C');

select distinct 
  sender, receiver
from 
  t
where 
  (sender, receiver) in (select receiver, sender from t);
```

Comment: your query taking too much time in my table that's why i could not check the result. Anyway thanks for help.